# codeigniter - relational table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter for the first time. I'm used to MVC but only .net, not PHP.

So, I have a table 'categories', a table 'countries', and a table 'category-countries'. Let's suppose the first 2 tables only have 'id' and 'name', and the third one have 'country_id' and 'category_id'. One category can have multiple countries assigned to it.

I have the models, views and controllers all ready to create and edit the categories.

**For the Edit functionallity**

Model:

```
function get_category_by_id($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('categories',array('id'=>$id));
    if($query->num_rows()<=0)
    {
        echo 'Invalid category id';die;
    }
    else
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="addcategory" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/category/updatecategory');?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $post->id;?>"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 control-label"><?php echo lang_key_admin('name');?>:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 controls">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $post->name;?>" placeholder="<?php echo lang_key_admin('type_something');?>" class="form-control input-sm" >
            <?php echo form_error('title'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function edit($id='')
{
    $value['post']  = $this->category_model->get_category_by_id($id);
    $data['title'] = lang_key_admin('edit_category');
    $data['content'] = load_admin_view('categories/editcategory_view',$value,TRUE);
    load_admin_view('template/template_view',$data);        
}

public function updatecategory()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', lang_key_admin('name'), 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $this->editcategory($id);   
    }
    else
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');

        $data                   = array();          
        $data['name']           = $this->input->post('name');           

            $this->category_model->update_category($data,$id);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success">'.lang_key_admin('data_updated').'</div>');

        redirect(site_url('admin/category/edit/'.$id));     
    }
}
```

Now I would like to add a select list (multiple select) to that view, so I can select which countries I want to assign to that category, and store the relation on the third table. How can I do it? I have to show all countries in the list and be able to select the ones I want. I also want the countries already assigned to appear selected in the list when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not writing code for you but will provide some guidance which I hope is helpful.

Your work will be easier if you become familiar with Codeigniter's [Form Helper.](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) In particular, to create a multiselect field for the form use the helper's [`form_multiselect()`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_multiselect) function.

You will need two model functions to gather two result sets: One to get the full list of countries and a second to get an array of country ids that match a particular category from your third table (let's name the table `crossref`). The first populates the multiselect, the second is use to indicate the currently selected set of countries in the multiselect.

These results are easily passed to `form_multiselect()` as are all the attributes (Bootstrap classes right?) for any form controls.

There are several ways to process a multiselect posted from a form. This [tutorial](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-select.html) may be helpful. (Scroll down a ways for the multiselect discussion.) Once you have parsed the selected countries a model function will be needed to insert to, or update `crossref`.

Not related to answering your question but something I noticed that you might wish to consider. Your model uses `echo` which is arguably a break from MVC best practice. In general the controller should be the decider on what is displayed based on results from any processing it initiates. So your model should probably do this instead of calling `echo` and `die`.

```
function get_category_by_id($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('categories',array('id'=>$id));
    return $query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->row() : NULL;
}
```

This will return NULL if there are no results. The controller must then check and react to the model's return

```
public function edit($id='')
{
    $category = $this->category_model->get_category_by_id($id);
    if(isset($category))
    {
        $value['post'] = $category;
        $data['title'] = lang_key_admin('edit_category');
        $data['content'] = load_admin_view('categories/editcategory_view',$value,TRUE);
        load_admin_view('template/template_view',$data); 
    }
    else
    {
        //handle the error (an "error" view?)
    }
}
```

**Do not** call the php functions `exit` or `die` when using CodeIgniter!

Why? The framework does not output anything to a browser until after the controller finishes executing. Calling either of those function will short-circuit the framework and, in your code, the message sent by`echo 'Invalid category id';` will not be displayed. CI does some other chores after the controller finishes too.

Using `exit` or `die` during development is OK, but not in a production site.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. They showed me the way. I will post the solution ASAP